# fstab configuration for esxi datastore-based hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, fstab

I've got the following drives on my server

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4571
loop1    7:1    0 86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
sda      8:0    0   16G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    1M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0   16G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0  1.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0  1.7T  0 part
sdc      8:32   0  1.7T  0 disk
```

I want to automount `sdb` and `sdc` each time the machine boots so went to edit fstab. I thought VMTools took care of this for me when using esxi though? It's running...

```
 ps -e | grep ".vm."
  284 ?        00:00:00 irq/16-vmwgfx
  480 ?        00:00:02 vmtoolsd
  486 ?        00:00:00 lvmetad
```

but when editing fstab there's only 2 lines

```
UUID=a8471d76-5173-11e8-9ea2-000c293859e1 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Can I just add something like this without bricking my VM?

```
/dev/sdb1    /myfolder/to/mount   ext4    defaults    0    1
```

Or is there something else i need to do? It's Ubuntu by the way, 18.04LTS 64bit. The hard drives are added in esxi & linked to vmware datastores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command:

`blkid`

That will give you the `UUID` and filesystem for each partition (or logical volume if you are using them). The filesystem will be listed as `TYPE=ext4` or whatever the filesystem may be.

If you want to mount it by UUID then just substitue it for `/dev/sdb1` in fstab so that it looks like this:

`UUID=the-uuid-for-dev-sdb1 /myfolder/to/mount ext4 defaults 0 0`

Obviously, you'd replace the above `UUID` part for the actual `UUID` of `/dev/sdb1`. Also, make sure that the filesystem type is correct by seeing that it matches with `TYPE` in the output of `blkid`.